# Is app engine more expensive when it's slower?

Tags: google-app-engine

There have been quite a few occasions recently when app engine appears to run slower. To some degree that's understandable with the architecture of their cloud platform. I'm not talking about new server instances - just requests to warm servers. I'm also just referring to CPU, not datastore API, but I do wonder about that as well.

It seems that during these slow periods I get a lot more yellow warnings on my requests - saying I am using a lot of CPU. Certainly they take longer to complete during this period.  What concerns me is that during these slow periods, my *billable* CPU seems to go up.

So to be clear - when app engine is fast, a request might complete in 100ms. In a slow period, it might take more than 1s for the same request. Same URI, same caching, same processing path, same datastore, same indexes - much more CPU. The yellow warnings, as I understand it, are referring to billable CPU usage, and there's many more of them when app engine is slower.

This seems to set up a bizarre situation where my app costs more to run when app engine performance is worse. This means google makes more money the more poorly the platform performs (up to the point where it fails or customers leave). Maybe I've got the situation all wrong, and it doesn't work like that - but if it does work like that, then as a customer the pressures and balances there are all wrong. That's not intimating any wrong-doing on google's part - just that the relationships between those two things don't seem right.

It almost seems like google's algorithm goes something like - 'If I give a processing job to a CPU and start my watch, then stop it when the job returns I get the billable CPU figure.' i.e. it doesn't measure CPU work at all. Surely that time should be divided by the number of processing jobs being concurrently executed plus some extra to cover the additional context switching. I'm sure that stuff is hard to measure - perhaps that's the reason.

I guess you could argue it is fair that you pay more when app engine is in high demand, but that makes budgeting close to impossible - you can't generate stats like '100 users costs me $1 a day', because that could change for a whole host of reasons - including app engine onboarding more customers than the infrastructure can realistically handle. If google over-subscribes app engine then all customers pay more - it's another relationship that doesn't sound right.  Surely google's costs should go *down* as they onboard more customers, and those customers use more resources - based on economies of scale.

Should I expect two identical requests in my app to cost me roughly the same amount each time they run - regardless of how much wall-time app engine takes to actually complete them? Have I misunderstood how this works?  If I haven't, is there a reason why I shouldn't be worried about it in the long term? Is there some documentation which makes this situation clearer? Cheers,

Colin

Comment: Seems like a fair question to me. I can report that I see the same thing although the performance range is far wider. They did try to compensate for this by turning off billing for datastore time, but this was recently re-enabled.

Comment: Google should be measuring CPU time and not wall clock time. Perhaps this is difficult to do with their infrastructure.

Comment: Agreed - there's a couple of suggestions in the comments below Greg's answer that would seem to represent reasonable solutions to the problem.

Comment: There can't be right answer, apart from google, who knows what actually happening. But I will say, its rather a dumb mistake, if they really missed such a big point. It may be the case of app caching and ALSO module caching. they may be unloading modules from time to time ( especially heavy like django in their own version of python ) that causing the said variation in timeframe.

Comment: In general when this occurring, *all* requests are returning more slowly (wall clock time), which points to increased load on app engine, rather than a specific request doing extra work on occasion. In this situation where the general response time of all requests is higher, it corresponds to increased cpu costs across most requests. It's not an occasional request, but a recurring pattern. I agree that someone from google is most likely able to shed light on this question.

Answer (score 3):

It would be more complicated, but they could change the billing algorithm to be a function of load. Or perhaps they could normalize the CPU measurements based on the performance of similar calls in the past.

I agree that this presents problems for the developers.

Comment: Agreed - they could also have a standard set of requests that they use themselves. Decide what the standard CPU use of those requests is, and then run them at regular intervals. If the result is 2x normal, then divide everyone's billable CPU by 2 for that period. Given the scale of their product, that should average out pretty well statistically if they choose a representative set of standard requests. Can't really see why this solution would be that tough to implement (and is roughly what you were saying I think). Thx.

Comment: I guess the converse of this is true as well, if app engine was running particularly fast, then increase everyone's CPU measurements. Given that google states the free quota is based on serving x million requests, it is surprising they aren't using this approach to normalise everything.

Comment: I know the GAE engineers are quite proud of their platform and are working hard to fix this. But I can't resist... the irony of course is, "You may have heard that here at Google we're obsessed with speed" and the fact that Google now uses site speed in their ranking algorithm. I wonder if they handicap the sites running on GAE. :) Sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true. It is a bummer. It also takes them over a second to start up my Java application (which I was billed  for) every time they decided my site was in low demand, and didn't need the resources.

I ended up using a cron to auto ping my site every minute to keep it warm.. doing all the wasted work made my bill cheaper, as it didn't have the startup time, instead it just had lots of 2ms pings...

Comment: Understand re. the cold starts - noted at the top that I was just referring to warm servers though. Just interested in the performance vs. cost question - don't want to make this a thread for a host of other gripes. Do you know for sure that google has set up app engine to be more expensive when it is slower, or are you just referring to anecdotal observations as I am? Ta.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears old and I think the pricing scheme must have changed...

The Google App Engine charges for "[instance hours](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing)" and the instances currently spawned are viewable in the GAE console. And Google provides adjustments so you can decide cost vs latency for your app.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

I did noticed that if the front-end is bogged down hitting a common backend resource that GAE will spawn a bunch of instances to get latency down. And you will pay for those instance hours even though latency/throughput doesn't improve. The adjustments I mentioned seem to help with that.